# WP v-5.5 $_GET parameter does not work in my plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I have developed a wordpress plugin. In my plugin I manage all pages by get parameters like `(http://example.com/client-portal/?page=dashboard)` and it was working till wordpress version 5.4

But new version of wordpress version 5.5 in automatically redirect `http://example.com/client-portal/?page=dashboard` to `http://example.com/client-portal/`. Get parameter vanished automatically.

**I have added shortcode by this way -**

```
//page short code for user page
add_shortcode( 'ccgclient_portal', array($this,'ccgclient_portal_shortcode_func') );
```

**This is my shortcode function -**

```
function ccgclient_portal_shortcode_func()
{
    ob_start();
    include_once 'pages/user/index.php';
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

**And catch get parameters by -**

```
if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'dashboard'){
     include_once 'dashboard.php';
}
```

I don't know what's wrong with the new version of wordpress (5.5).

Please can you help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot use WP reserved terms: https://codex.wordpress.org/Reserved_Terms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue is with the 'page' key, this is a post type slug and it's creating a conflict with WP in this version. This is the same as configuring the permalink to work with '?post=98979' or a similar format.
My suggestion is to try and use a different get key and see what happens.

Let me know what you get.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with my plugin.
My problem was not using a new key. My client defined "page" here. It is about all the old links around in the world.

Im my case I solved it like this:

```
add_action( 'parse_request', 'ai_parse_request', 1);
```

and in

```
function ai_parse_request( $query ) { 
    unset( $query->query_vars['page']); 
    return $query;
}
```

I remove the "page" parameter from the $query to avoid the 301 redirect.

I have made this "workaround" configurable as the page parameter is used actually for pagination in the blog. In you case you should only apply this if e.g. the parameter is not a number to make sure you don't break pagination globally!